# What happens - NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet.fetchMoreResults

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

`cassandra-connector-assembly-2.0.0` built from `github` project.

with `Scala 2.11.8`, `cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0`

```
sc.cassandraTable("mykeyspace", "mytable").select("something").where("key=?", key).mapPartitions(par => {
    par.map({ row => (row.getString("something"), 1 ) })
})
.reduceByKey(_ + _).collect().foreach(println)
```

The same job works fine for reading less mass data

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet.fetchMoreResults()Lshade/com/datastax/spark/connector/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.reader.PrefetchingResultSetIterator.maybePrefetch(PrefetchingResultSetIterator.scala:26)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.reader.PrefetchingResultSetIterator.next(PrefetchingResultSetIterator.scala:39)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.reader.PrefetchingResultSetIterator.next(PrefetchingResultSetIterator.scala:17)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.next(CountingIterator.scala:16)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can any one suggest or point out to the issue, and a possible solution?

Comment: Well I removed libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "3.1.2" from the project and whatever built-in cassandra driver core Spark has embedded in it works for the rest of my project as a Cassandra driver and solves the fetchMoreResults issue. Also I can't find where Spark has this Cassandra Core jar, it's not in the jars/ directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a conflict with the Cassandra driver-core that

```
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.11" % "2.0.0-M3"
```

brings in.

If you go into the ~/.ivy2/cache/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11 you will find a file called ivy-2.0.0-M3.xml

In that file the dependency is

```
com.datastax.cassandra" name="cassandra-driver-core" rev="3.0.2" force="true"
```

Note that it is the 3.0.2 version of Cassandra driver core which gets overrun by the more recent one.

It just so happens that [the latest source on Github does not show a implementation for fetchMoreResults](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.java) which is inherited from interface PagingIterable

If you roll back the Git version to 3.0.x on Github, you'll find

```
 public ListenableFuture<ResultSet> fetchMoreResults();
```

So it looks like the newest Cassandra core drivers were rushed out the door incomplete. Or I might be missing something. Hope this helps.

tl;dr; Remove the latest driver and use the one embedded in the spark cassandra connector.

Answer (score 4):

had the same problem

There were two dependencies in the project which both had `cassandra-driver-core` as a dependency

`spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.0.0-M3` &
`job-server-api_2.10-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT`

spark-cassandra-connecter expected `ResultSet.fetchMoreResults` to have a different return type, due to its  [shading of guava](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/4a4ae757675d37312ee127d87ca65e2092db8114/project/Settings.scala)

expected . `shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture`

found . 
`com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture`

switched to an [unshaded version of cassandra-connector](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector-unshaded_2.10/2.0.0-M3) to correct the issue

Comment: Best answer! Lifesaver!

Comment: I was looking for this fix very badly too. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved by removing **cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0-shaded.jar** from spark/jars/

a topical java **duplicated classes conflicted** problem?!

Need to confirm all jars included, if there're any duplicated jars involved.

The solution mentioned above is only one of case.

Comment: Do you have more details about the resolution? I don't see cassandra-driver-core-3.1.0-shaded.jar anywhere. spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.0.0-M3 includes a ResultSet class from version 1 of the core, which obviously causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

For all these problems run below command and check if there is any overlapping dependency exists-

mvn dependency:tree