# Conflicting maven dependencies in using both Spark and Flink Cassandra connectors

Tags: maven, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-flink

I'm working on a project that both Apache Flink and Apache Spark try to read/write data from/to Apache Cassandra, so I should use Spark and Flink Cassandra connectors Maven dependencies that both have the following sub dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>*</version>
</dependency>
```

My problem will raise when I try to use Spark for reading/writing from/to Cassandra. The error has been discussed [here](http://com/datastax/spark/connector/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034538/what-happens-nosuchmethoderror-com-datastax-driver-core-resultset-fetchmorere). I want to know how can I solve the conflicts in Maven? I tried excluding the package `cassandra-driver-core`:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-cassandra_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

but no differences! Just when I remove `Flink-Cassandra-connector` Maven dependency, Spark works without error. How can I fix that?

Comment: The usual way is trying back and forth with different versions of spark, flink and cassandra until it starts to work...

Comment: There is not any way to exclude `cassandra-driver-core` from Flink-Cassandra-connector dependency? I tried using Maven exclusion but it was not useful!

Comment: If you write the exclusion, it will be excluded. Have a look at `dependency:tree` to see from where you really get your cassandra-driver-core.

Comment: Nice, I'm new to Maven, Could you pls say how can I found dependency tree for a specific artifact in my projects? any commands or else. I use IntellijIDE

Comment: You start the Maven goal `dependency:tree` (just like `clean install`). I am an Eclipse user and cannot say exactly where you do it in IntelliJ.

Comment: I tried the command `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core` but I just got the output: `--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ MYPROJECT ---` what does it mean?

Comment: Probably that the artifact is not present. Try `dependency:list` to see the full list of included artifacts with versions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171982/discussion-between-soheil-pourbafrani-and-jf-meier).

Comment: The cassandra driver is shaded in that release, so it wouldn't be conflicting. What's the actual error?

Comment: Why do you want to use both flink and spark connectors at the same time? Can't you have too separate jars for running on both platforms? And build them e.g. with two different profiles?

Comment: @RussS I mentioned two question about that error in the post.

Comment: @DawidWysakowicz Thanks, It makes sense! I try building Flink-Cassandra-connector against my desired datastax driver version and if it was conflicting again, I will do as your suggestion.