# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet.fetchMoreResults()

Tags: maven, apache-spark, cassandra, dependencies, spark-cassandra-connector

This problem is similar as:

[What happens - NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet.fetchMoreResults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034538/what-happens-nosuchmethoderror-com-datastax-driver-core-resultset-fetchmorere)

Whenever I am trying to query cassandra table, it is always giving me following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet.fetchMoreResults()Lshade/com/datastax/spark/connector/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.reader.PrefetchingResultSetIterator.maybePrefetch(PrefetchingResultSetIterator.scala:26) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.0.8.jar!/:2.0.8]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.reader.PrefetchingResultSetIterator.next(PrefetchingResultSetIterator.scala:39) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.0.8.jar!/:2.0.8]
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.reader.PrefetchingResultSetIterator.next(PrefetchingResultSetIterator.scala:17) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.0.8.jar!/:2.0.8]
```

Since the ResultSet class is present in both cassandra-driver-core and spark-cassandra-connector.

Previous posts suggest to delete the cassandra-driver-core jar since it is confilcting with spark-cassandra-connector embedded driver.

Here are the solutions I tried so far:

1. removing cassandra-driver-core dependency from pom
2. excluding cassandra-driver-core from spark-cassandra-connector dependency using

```js
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
            <exclusions> 
                <exclusion> 
                    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

but none of them worked, every time I rebuild my code, the cassandra-driver-core jar reappears and gives the same error.

I also tried it removing manually from project jar, but then the project is not able to connect to cassandra DB.

Is there any solution to this dependency conflict.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: how do you build your spark job?

Comment: I created sparkConf file to create a javaSparkContext and sparkSession to connect it to my Java REST API.

Comment: I meant - do you build the fat jar (assembly)?

Comment: no.. it was not required for Springboot-cassandra integration.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this. I removed the spark-cassandra-connector and used a spark-cassandra-connector-unshaded dependency. 
The reason for using unshaded dependency is that, since previously the REST API was reading the Resultset class from Guava which does not contain the fetchMoreResult Method. 
Using unshaded version, removes that conflict somehow and make the call to cassandra-driver-core jar.

Also, while adding the unshaded  dependency, it was giving "Artifact Missing Error" since STS was unable to download the required jar. So had to download the jar and place it in unshaded folder manually.